# How to access and confirm the transfer of my SelectedListItem TEXT from my dropdownlist from one view to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I start the INDEX page by filling up the `IEnumerable` list for a `DropDownListFor()`. Then I send the model to the INDEX View.
The photo in the bottom shows what the INDEX looks like with the two textboxs and the dropdownlist.

Once the submit button is pressed I want the information to be printed in the ABOUT page to make sure the information is transferring. Specifically I want the TEXT of the `SelectedListItem`chosen from the `DropDownListFor()`.

I tried transferring the TEXT of the selected value to the ABOUT View with the line `input.SelectedText = input.SelectedType.Text;`. This is inside the ABOUT default action but it never returns the string I set it too. Why is my `SelectedListItem` not transferring?

**Model**

```
public class UserInputModel
    {
        public SelectListItem SelectedType { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Type { get; set; }
        public string SelectedText { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Path { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Find{ get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FillType(IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list)
        {
            list = new[]
            {
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Xml" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Html" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Css" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "C#" }

            };
            return list;
        }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class FindController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var input = new UserInputModel();
            input.Type=input.FillType(input.Type);
            return View(input);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(UserInputModel input)
        {

            return View("About", input);
        }

        public ActionResult About(UserInputModel input)
        {


            input.SelectedText = input.SelectedType.Text;
            return View(input); 
        }
    }
```

**View "Index"**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Find", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Hello There", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <input type="hidden" id="hidText" name="hidText" />
        <div class="form-group">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedType, Model.Type, "Select a File Type", new { @class = "form-control", name = "type" })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Path, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Path, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", name = "path" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Path, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

       @* <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedFolder, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedFolder, new SelectList(Model.DirectoryFolders), "Select a Folder:", new { @class = "form-control" })

        </div>
    </div>
    *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Find, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Find, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", name = "find" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Find, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />


            </div>
        </div>

   </div> 
}
```

**View "About"**

```
<body>
    <div> 
        <h3>Selected:@Model.SelectedText</h3>
        <h3>Path:@Model.Path</h3>
        <h3>Find:@Model.Find</h3>
    </div>
</body>
```

[INDEX View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRuca.png)

[ABOUT View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w0cK.png)

Any other feedback on good and bad practices would be helpful since this is my first time working with MVC.

Comment: A `<select>` posts back the value of its selected option, not its display text. And you cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object (which is what `SelectedType` is) - you need to change the property to `public int SelectedType { get; set; }` - and if you want the display text in the post method, then look it up again.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you again @StephenMuecke.